# BeautifulSoup y obtener un dato vacío

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Hola tengo un fragemento de código y quiero obtener el valor correspondiente. Utilizo la función next_sibling para obtener el dato, pero querría como hacer para encontrar el dato vacío

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

variable = '<p style="display:block"><strong>Nombre: </strong>Hola mundo<br/><strong>Teléfono: </strong>+XXX XX XXX XX X<br/></p>'
# Analizo el texto html
bs = BeautifulSoup(variable, 'html.parser')
Datos = bs.find_all('p', {"style":"display:block"})
for dato in Datos:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(str(dato),'html.parser')
    # Quiero sacar Hola +XXX XX XXX XX X
    label = soup.find("strong", text="Teléfono: ")
    if label is not None:
        print(label.next_sibling.strip())
    # Quiero sacar Hola Mundo
    label = soup.find("strong", text="Nombre: ")
    if label is not None:
        print(label.next_sibling.strip())
# Ahora quiero encontrar el dato vacío de la siguiente variable
variable = '<p style="display:block"><strong>Nombre: </strong><br/><strong>Teléfono: </strong>+YYY TT ZZZ RR SS<br/></p>'
# Analizo el texto html
bs = BeautifulSoup(variable, 'html.parser')
Datos = bs.find_all('p', {"style":"display:block"})
for dato in Datos:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(str(dato),'html.parser')
    # Quiero sacar Hola +YYY TT ZZZ RR SS
    label = soup.find("strong", text="Teléfono: ")
    if label is not None:
        print(label.next_sibling.strip())
    # Quiero sacar vacío
    label = soup.find("strong", text="Nombre: ")
    if label is not None:
        print(label.next_sibling.strip())
```

Me interesa saber como poder obtener el dato vacío de **Nombre:** 
 si no puedo llamar a la función next_sibling cuando no hay dato.

el resultado de la ejecución del código es

```
+XXX XX XXX XX X
Hola mundo
+YYY TT ZZZ RR SS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kk.py", line 31, in <module>
    print(label.next_sibling.strip())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

Estudiando los tipos de datos que van apareciendo en los datos he utilizado esto

```
label = soup.find("strong", text="Nombre: ")
if label is not None:
    #print(label.find_next_sibling())
    print('NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN') #
    print(type(label.next_sibling)) #<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
    print(label.next_sibling) #<br/>
    if isinstance(label.next_sibling, NavigableString):
        print(label.next_sibling.strip()) #'NoneType' object is not callable
    else:
        print('Nombre Vacío')
        
    print(type(label)) #<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
    print(label) #<strong>Nombre: </strong>
```

Así el código quedaría para encontrar el campo vacío

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

variable = '<p style="display:block"><strong>Nombre: </strong>Hola mundo<br/><strong>Teléfono: </strong>+XXX XX XXX XX X<br/></p>'
# Analizo el texto html
bs = BeautifulSoup(variable, 'html.parser')
Datos = bs.find_all('p', {"style":"display:block"})
for dato in Datos:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(str(dato),'html.parser')
    # Quiero sacar Hola +XXX XX XXX XX X
    label = soup.find("strong", text="Teléfono: ")
    if label is not None:
        print(label.next_sibling.strip())
    # Quiero sacar Hola Mundo
    label = soup.find("strong", text="Nombre: ")
    if label is not None:
        print(label.next_sibling.strip())
# Ahora quiero encontrar el dato vacío de la siguiente variable
variable = '<p style="display:block"><strong>Nombre: </strong><br/><strong>Teléfono: </strong>+YYY TT ZZZ RR SS<br/></p>'
# Analizo el texto html
print('+++++++++++++++++')
bs = BeautifulSoup(variable, 'html.parser')
Datos = bs.find_all('p', {"style":"display:block"})
for dato in Datos:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(str(dato),'html.parser')
    # Quiero sacar Hola +YYY TT ZZZ RR SS
    label = soup.find("strong", text="Teléfono: ")
    if label is not None:
        #print(label.find_next_sibling())
        print('TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT')
        print(type(label.next_sibling)) #<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
        print(label.next_sibling) #+YYY TT ZZZ RR SS
        print(label.next_sibling.strip()) #+YYY TT ZZZ RR SS
        print(type(label)) #<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
        print(label) #<strong>Teléfono: </strong>
    # Quiero sacar vacío
    label = soup.find("strong", text="Nombre: ")
    if label is not None:
        #print(label.find_next_sibling())
        print('NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN') #
        print(type(label.next_sibling)) #<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
        print(label.next_sibling) #<br/>
        if isinstance(label.next_sibling, NavigableString):
            print(label.next_sibling.strip()) #'NoneType' object is not callable
        else:
            print('Nombre Vacío')
            
        print(type(label)) #<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
        print(label) #<strong>Nombre: </strong>
```